# Making GeoServer run as Windows Service after being installed?

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows

While installing GeoServer, on my windows machine, I selected the 'Run manually' as the option.

[image]

Now I wish to keep it running all the time, and for this, I would have to run it as a Windows service.

I know that I can manually make a new service and run it from there, but is there a better way to make it run as a Service, without reinstalling it?

Comment: Added other options to create a service though I still think reinstalling would be less messy and has no bad side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reinstall it and keep your old settings. Just make sure to point to your old data directory. Windows will still only record one installation of Geoserver. All your settings will be preserved, too. Tested on a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit machine with the Geoserver 2.2 installer.

Other options are Microsoft's [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) executable and [Tanuksi Software's Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-features.html) though I wouldn't call those options better. If you prefer GUIs then [ServiceShell](http://www.uinterface.com/serviceshell/) might be more to your liking.

[image]

Comment: I belive You can't reinstall Geoserver without losing part of Your configuration (Jetty, container etc)?
I ran into same issue, I installed Geoserver win installer and as service, but needed to change Java options (as usual). I did it wrapper/wrapper.config. Reinstalling will whipe them out. So it is not ideal solution.